# Transformation of Random Variable - Not Monotonic Case

Tags: random-variables, inverse-function

Let random variable $X \thicksim U(-2,3)$  where $U$ denotes uniform distribution. Then I'd like to derive the probability density function of $Y = X^2$

but this case not like strictly increasing or decreasing case, for example for X=3, there exists two different variable $Y$ such as $Y = \sqrt 3$ and $-\sqrt 3$

Then do I have to just allocate $1/2 \cdot 1/5$ for each case?

I've never thought of it is possible to derive pdf from not inverse mapping exisiting condition.

Any help to understand this case?

Comment: Yes you have to add the positive and the negative part together.  $P(1\leq X^2\leq 2)=P(-\sqrt{2}\leq X\leq-1) + P(1\leq X\leq \sqrt{2})$ for example.